# Cannot create or edit emails or templates in Mosaico

Tags: mosaico

Just migrated a WordPress site to a new server. When we try to create, edit or adjust a template that uses Mosaico we cannot get the following (this is from the edit mosaico templates page and the console shows 404 errors.

[image: template screen]

[image: Console 404 errors]

We have done the following:

- Checked both directories & resource urls settings. We have also put hte full paths in these settings
- Cleared Cache
- Reinstalled Mosaico & Flexmailer
- Upgraded CiviCRM from 5.28.2 to 5.28.4

It seems Mosaico cannot load the requested

Comment: Try deleting everything in the `templates_c` dir. Also, Mosaico hard-codes a lot of its paths/urls in the database. Calling the API3 `Job.mosaico_migrate` action may help (backup first). https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/blob/2.x/api/v3/Job/MosaicoMigrate.php

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue was being caused by the resource url for the extensions directory. The path was set correctly but the resource url had a typo. The extension directory was not the standard /ext. Once the resource url was corrected and the cache cleared all works fine.